# i want to install laravel/horizon but it give error laravel v9

Tags: php, laravel, horizon

i write composer require laravel/horizon to composer but it give this error :

**Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**

**Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires laravel/horizon ^0.1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/horizon[v0.1.0].
- laravel/horizon v0.1.0 requires illuminate/contracts ~5.4 -> found illuminate/contracts[v5.4.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.**

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/horizon:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/horizon:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

`my composer.json` :

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.11",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: i solved that with this code : composer require laravel/horizon:^v5.9.7 --ignore-platform-req=ext-pcntl --ignore-platform-req=ext-posix

Comment: Why are you trying to require laravel/horizon ^0.1.0? The latest version at this time is 5.9.7. Obviously the old version of horizon requires old dependencies, and those conflict with what you already have installed. Don't specify a version, just do `composer require laravel/horizon` and let Composer detect the appropriate version for you.

Comment: @jurchiks please read my problem correctly i already use composer require laravel/horizon and it give error : Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1 - Root composer.json requires laravel/horizon ^0.1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/horizon[v0.1.0]. - laravel/horizon v0.1.0 requires illuminate/contracts ~5.4 -> found illuminate/contracts[v5.4.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Comment: you're not reading what I wrote either. You're trying to require `laravel/horizon ^0.1.0`, which is an ANCIENT version. 0.1.0 was released on Jul 26, 2017.
And your `composer.json` does not contain an entry for `laravel/horizon`, so it's apparent you're trying to require it from CLI.
Although it could be that your `composer.lock` contains `laravel/horizon` while your .json does not, in which case you should just delete that lock file and rerun `composer install`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i solved that with this code :
composer require laravel/horizon:^v5.9.7 --ignore-platform-req=ext-pcntl --ignore-platform-req=ext-posix

Comment: Your answer does not explain WHY your solution works, not to mention the unnecessary `--ignore-platform-req` parameters which he definitely should not have to use. There's a reason why those extensions are required by the library.

Answer (score 0):

When using `composer require` without a version constraint. It will automatically pick the highest *compatible* package version for you. Because your PHP installation does not contain the `pctnl` extension, the latest version that you "can" install is v0.1.0. You can see the extension getting added in v0.2.0 ([Commit](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/commit/85b6bf801511189d4cd956a4a7f2ba52f743db5a))

Using the `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag is a bad practice most of the time. Sure, it will install the package for you. But these extensions are crucial when running Laravel Horizon properly. Ignoring the error is not the correct option here. Please look for a way to install/enable the missing extensions on your system.

The latest `laravel/horizon` version requires 3 PHP extensions: `json`, `pcntl` & `posix`. I normally

You can check which extensions are installed with the following command:

```bash
php -m
```

Alternatively, you can also check if the extensions are installed by pasting those requirements in the `composer.json` file and just run `composer update` to see if you are missing any extensions:

```json
{
  "require": {
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-pcntl": "*",
    "ext-posix": "*",
    // Other requirements ...
  }
}
```